# How to create SLD with inline features and style and add to WMS using GeoTools?

Tags: geoserver, sld, geotools

I am trying to create labels with arbitrary values on a WMS map using GeoTools (9.4). I have created a feature type, a feature (in a data store), and a user layer. With that I generated an SLD document and sent it to Geoserver.

Here is my code:

```
double x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max, width, height, x_center, y_center;

x_min = -10491786.13906;
y_min = 3869280.8541878;
x_max = -10478619.86094;
y_max = 3877727.1458122;

width = x_max - x_min;
height = y_max - y_min;

x_center = x_min + height / 2;
y_center = y_min + height / 2;

//  Create labels
SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder b = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
b.setName("ml");
b.setNamespaceURI("http://www.mylabel.com/");
b.setSRS("EPSG:900913");
b.add("geom", Point.class);
b.add("label", Integer.class);

SimpleFeatureType sft = b.buildFeatureType();

SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(sft);
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();

Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(x_center, y_center));
featureBuilder.add(point);
featureBuilder.add(1);

SimpleFeature feature = featureBuilder.buildFeature(null);

List<SimpleFeature> features = new ArrayList<SimpleFeature>();

features.add(feature);

MemoryDataStore mds = new MemoryDataStore(sft);

mds.addFeatures(features);


//  Create symbolization
StyleFactory sf = CommonFactoryFinder.getStyleFactory();
FilterFactory ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory();

Fill fillFont = sf.createFill(ff.literal("#ff0000"));
Font[] font = new Font[1];
font[0] = sf.createFont(ff.literal("sans-serif"), ff.literal("normal"), ff.literal("normal"), ff.literal(12));
Fill fillHalo = sf.createFill(ff.literal("#ffffff"));
Halo halo = sf.createHalo(fillHalo, ff.literal(3));
AnchorPoint ap = sf.createAnchorPoint(ff.literal(0.5), ff.literal(0.5));
Displacement d = sf.createDisplacement(ff.literal(0), ff.literal(0));
PointPlacement pp = sf.createPointPlacement(ap, d, ff.literal(0));
Symbolizer symbolizer = sf.createTextSymbolizer(fillFont, font, halo, ff.literal("label"), pp, "geom");
Style style = sf.createStyle();
style.setName("my-label");
StyleBuilder sb = new StyleBuilder();
style.featureTypeStyles().add(sb.createFeatureTypeStyle("my-label", new Symbolizer[] { symbolizer }));


//  Create SLD
StyledLayerDescriptor sld = sf.createStyledLayerDescriptor();
UserLayer ul = sf.createUserLayer();
ul.setInlineFeatureDatastore(mds);
ul.setInlineFeatureType(sft);
ul.addUserStyle(style);
sld.addStyledLayer(ul);

/*
// use UserLayerBuilder
UserLayerBuilder ulb = new UserLayerBuilder();
ulb.inlineData(mds, TYPE);
StyledLayerDescriptor sld = ulb.buildSLD();
*/

SLDTransformer styleTransform = new SLDTransformer();
String sXml = styleTransform.transform(sld);

//  Create map
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9080/geoserver/wms");
WebMapServer wms = new WebMapServer(url);

WMSCapabilities capabilities = wms.getCapabilities();
org.geotools.data.ows.Layer[] layers = WMSUtils.getNamedLayers(capabilities);

GetMapRequest map_request = wms.createGetMapRequest();
map_request.setFormat("image/png");
map_request.setDimensions(100, 100);
map_request.setTransparent(true);
map_request.setSRS("EPSG:900913");
map_request.setBBox(new Double(x_min).toString() + "," + new Double(y_min).toString() + "," + new Double(x_max).toString() + "," + new Double(y_max).toString());

map_request.setProperty(GetMapRequest.SLD_BODY, URLEncoder.encode(sXml, "UTF-8"));

GetMapResponse map_response = (GetMapResponse)wms.issueRequest(map_request);
```

Here is the SLD document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.0.0">
<sld:UserLayer>
<sld:InlineFeature>
<FeatureCollection>
<gml:boundedBy>
<gml:Box srsName="900913">
<gml:coordinates xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">-1.04875629932E7,3873504 -1.04875629932E7,3873504</gml:coordinates>
</gml:Box>
</gml:boundedBy>
<gml:featureMember>
<ml fid="fid--57398c6c_140a74006e1_-7fdf">
<:geom>
<gml:Point srsName="900913">
<gml:coordinates xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">-1.04875629932E7,3873504</gml:coordinates>
</gml:Point>
</:geom>
<:label>1</:label>
</:ml>
</gml:featureMember>
</FeatureCollection>
</sld:InlineFeature>
<sld:LayerFeatureConstraints>
<sld:FeatureTypeConstraint/>
</sld:LayerFeatureConstraints>
<sld:UserStyle>
<sld:Name>my-label</sld:Name>
<sld:Title/>
<sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
<sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
<sld:FeatureTypeName>my-label</sld:FeatureTypeName>
<sld:Rule>
<sld:TextSymbolizer>
<sld:Geometry>
<ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
</sld:Geometry>
<sld:Label>label</sld:Label>
<sld:Font>
<sld:CssParameter name="font-family">sans-serif</sld:CssParameter>
<sld:CssParameter name="font-size">12</sld:CssParameter>
<sld:CssParameter name="font-style">normal</sld:CssParameter>
<sld:CssParameter name="font-weight">normal</sld:CssParameter>
</sld:Font>
<sld:LabelPlacement>
<sld:PointPlacement>
<sld:AnchorPoint>
<sld:AnchorPointX>0.5</sld:AnchorPointX>
<sld:AnchorPointY>0.5</sld:AnchorPointY>
</sld:AnchorPoint></sld:PointPlacement>
</sld:LabelPlacement>
<sld:Halo>
<sld:Radius>3</sld:Radius>
<sld:Fill>
<sld:CssParameter name="fill">#ffffff</sld:CssParameter>
</sld:Fill>
</sld:Halo>
<sld:Fill>
<sld:CssParameter name="fill">#ff0000</sld:CssParameter>
</sld:Fill>
</sld:TextSymbolizer>
</sld:Rule>
</sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
</sld:UserStyle>
</sld:UserLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Geoserver returns the following error:

```
Element type "ml" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

I am expecting an image with a "1" in the center.

The problem seems to be related to a missing namespace, but I don't know how to correct that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [example here](https://wiki.state.ma.us/display/massgis/GeoServer+-+SLD+-+Inline+Feature) you need to have a namespace for your feature or nothing at all (so no `:`):

```
    <sld:InlineFeature>
        <sld:FeatureCollection>
           <sld:featureMember>
              <polygonProperty>
                 <gml:Polygon>
                    <gml:outerBoundaryIs>
                       <gml:LinearRing>
                          <gml:coordinates>240167.78347885,869905.5610437
                             249317.75340551,869905.5610437 249317.75340551,879026.25071433
                             240167.78347885,879026.25071433
                          240167.78347885,869905.5610437</gml:coordinates>
                       </gml:LinearRing>
                    </gml:outerBoundaryIs>
                 </gml:Polygon>
              </polygonProperty>
           </sld:featureMember>
        </sld:FeatureCollection>
     </sld:InlineFeature>
```

Also if you want to refer to the label elelment of the feature then you need a `<PropertyName>` tag around `label` in the `<label>` tag.